# Django Templates: no output in template if statment

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a base template with a header include in it. The header include contains the code below.

However for some reason I get no output in between the if block, any reason why? ps no errors. The rest of the template outputs just fine.

**base.html**

```
<body>
    {% include 'includes/header.html' %}
    {% block sliderWrapper %}{% endblock %}
    {% block titleWrapper %}{% endblock %}
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            {% block mainWrapper %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% include 'includes/footer.html' %}
    {% include 'includes/copyright.html' %}
    {% include 'includes/js.html' %}
</body>
```

content of {% include 'includes/header.html' %} below.... everything shows just not the two login/logout links. take them out the block and they show. neither statement shows in the if

```
   <div class="span9">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                                <ul class="nav">
                                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='{% url django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage url="how-it-works/" %}'>How does it work?</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='{% url django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage url="how-it-works/" %}'>Download</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/member/registration/">Register</a></li>
                                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                        <li><a href="/member/logout/">Logout</a></li>
                                    {% else % }
                                        <li><a href="/member/login/">Login</a></li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth" is installed and sessions in enabled.

If I output `{{ user }}` i get AnonymousUser which is what I except, so, one would assume the 'else' condition would fire, however neither conditions seem to be met.

The request context is being passed also...

```
return render_to_response('pageRegistration.html', context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: does you have more than one "includes/header.html" files in different apps? maybe you're just rendering a different one?

Comment: @furins nope its right, the rest of the stuff in the include shows only the 'if statement' does not. take them out and they appear again.

Comment: Yeah sometimes it happenes. I am not sure why. Just try is_anonymous() once and see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a syntax error in your code that passed by unnoticed:

```
{% else % }
```

should be:

```
{% else %}
```

Django template system probably looks for a regex `{%...%}`, and as that didn't match, it was regarded simply as text inside the `{% if %}{% endif %}` node.